# Problem - SharePoint Workflow runs as previous version when an email is received

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, workflow, document-library

I have modified a SharePoint visual studio workflow which works as per requirement on the dev machine. I have to deploy it to an email enabled document library on sharepoint server and it is set to be started automatically when a new item is added to the library. When i deploy it to the server, and perform a manual upload to the doc library i.e. use the upload button to uplaod a document, it runs as expected. but when an email is received by the document library, a previous version of the workflow runs. this is really frustrating. I have removed all the previous versions of the workflow and now there is only one left. I have tried removing the workflow and adding it again but still the same behavior. I have removed temporary .net files from the windows folder but no luck.

If the new version is not installed properly, why is the manual upload working fine? can someone help? I want the same version of the workflow to run on the manual upload and email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to restart Windows Sharepoint Services Timer Service (OWSTIMER.EXE) as this service has probably cached your old DLL.

Because OWSTIMER.EXE is the service that wakes up your workflow after event has occurred.

Answer (score 0):

build the DLL with a new version number and deploy it once more and see if it helps.